# How can I programmatically recycle a .net web app's own apppool?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a complex server application that uses Nhibernate and Linq2SQL. About 3 times per day the Linq2sql code generates a "value cannot be null" exception. Once this happens, the code will always generate the exception. Diagnosis and solving the root cause will be lengthy and will introduce instability.

The current "fix" is to recyle the app pool every hour. However, the service is down from the point the problem happens until the recycle occurs. I want the web service to catch the exception and recycle it's own app pool. I want all other web requests to be honored until they are completed.

**Edit:** The fault is on both servers on a load balanced web farm. Clients do not switch from one server to the other just because this code crashes.

Comment: `Diagnosis and solving the root cause will be lengthy and will introduce instability` in before downvotealanche.  You should configure the application pool to recycle in the short term, and fix that bug in the long term.

Comment: The best approach will be to fix the bug

Comment: Yes, that's totally true. I'm the first one to agree that once you put in a band-aid you tend to live with it. In this case, the old code is so mangled that a work around not involving a human is required until we can schedule the fault analysis time, which I know will involve some dangerous re-factoring.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The following code will recycle the current site's app pool. You need to add a reference to Microsoft.Web.Administration

```
using (ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager())
{
    SiteCollection sites = iisManager.Sites;
    foreach (Site site in sites)
    {
       if (site.Name == HostingEnvironment.SiteName) 
       {
         iisManager.ApplicationPools[site.Applications["/"].ApplicationPoolName].Recycle();
         break;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: @vittore Have a similar problem as OP, and this won't cut it. The APPPOOL don't have the rights to pull this off, so maybe it doesn't work for OP either. OP's solution would work for me, but it just feels *creepy* ;) doing it that way.

Comment: @ClasG Yeah you need extended permissions for that to work

Comment: Do you have any details on what permissions it needs and how to go about doing this?  We are running into a similar issue but it is file locks that is causing an issue on code deployment (we need to wipe a directory first and it screws up web deploy when files get locked).

Comment: I'm calling this from a different site that has crazy authentication and admin rights. I didn't want the app pool to recycle itself or somehow.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to "trip" the ASP.NET worker process into recycling an application pool is to modify the web.config file in some way. This change is picked up by the file system watcher and causes ASP.NET to recycle in order to load the new configuration.

The content of the file doesn't have to change in any practical way; just adding or removing whitespace character is enough.

**Edit:**

If this isn't strong enough to work around your problem, you can go the whole hog and use Directory Services to recycle the app pool manually.

```
// Set up the path identifying your application pool.
var path = "IIS://YOURSERVERNAME/W3SVC/AppPools/YourAppPoolName";

// Create the directory entry to control the app pool
var appPool = new DirectoryEntry(path);

// Invoke the recycle action.
appPool.Invoke("Recycle", null);
```

Based on [Code Project: Recycling IIS 6.0 application pools programmatically](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26430/Recycling-IIS-6-0-application-pools-programmatical).

Comment: Touching web.config, even if I explicitly grant write rights to IUSR (it is a band aid remember) will only recycle the APPLICATION, not the APP POOL. The data problem is in the app pool and the w3wp process continues on merrily

Comment: Updated with a more direct approach. It's not been verified to work on IIS7+, so let us know how you get on.

Comment: I had originally gone down this path but the list of permissions required was onerous as well as complex. I settled on a much simpler solution, which was to enable the app pool's setting to recycle on exceeding the memoryLimit value then deliberately allocating memory until the recycling was tripped.

Comment: have you seen http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling

Answer (score -1):

I've had the exact same problem before; I should have blogged about it because now I can't remember the root cause.

My gut tells me, it was one of the following:

1. A context not getting disposed somewhere.
2. Threading issue: make sure multiple threads can't access the same context.

Or something along those lines. Just make sure you're using Linq2Sql correctly.

Answer (score -2):

The solution I eventually chose was to set a maximum value for the amount of memory the appPool was allowed to consume. The code then simply gobbled memory until asp.net decided to recycle the appPool.

In the App pool advanced settings I set the Private Memory Limit to 800,000 Kb.

In the Catch section where the Linq code failed, I allocate more memory than the limit:

```
List<string> listOfMemory = new List<string>();

// in the app pool, you need to set the virtual memory limit to 800,000kb
log.Error("Allocating so much memory that the app pool will be forced to recycle... ");
for (int intCount = 1; intCount < 10000000; intCount++)
{
listOfMemory.Add("new string " + intCount.ToString());
}
```

This now means only about 4 threads fail before a new w3wp process is spawned. Prior to this solution, threads would consistently fail until a human recycled the app pool manually. Unfortunately, if you set the app pool to recycle on a regular number of minutes, the smaller the number of minutes the more often the crash. And the larger the number of minutes, the more threads would fail.

This creative workaround limits the damage.

Comment: While this might be suitable for your environment, it could also hose the server temporarily if: your app is using 200 mb memory, the server has 400 mb memory free, your app starts to allocate memory. At this point you need 600 mb to force a recycle, and the server is going to start to page heavily after 400 mb is allocated.

Comment: Wow... pretty ugly. But even if you want to do it this way, why not just new[] whatever amount of RAM you want to allocate?