# ASP.NET: How to delete all session variables from all users?

Tags: asp.net, session

We have ASP.NET application and want to delete all session variables from all sessions from all users?

I mean not to delete session variables from current session only using:

```
Session.Clear();
```

or:

```
Session.Abandon();
```

We need to clear the session variables from other user's session as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to Destroy all sessions at one Time in asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172268/how-to-destroy-all-sessions-at-one-time-in-asp-net)

Comment: Have al look to this Answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172268/how-to-destroy-all-sessions-at-one-time-in-asp-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot clear all session, instead fing a away to recycle app_pool which will automatically clear the sessions. See here-->

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9470372/823161

Comment: That's a very creative solution to the problem. I never would have thought of that.

Comment: That's pretty overkill for a solution. Causing the whole app pool to recycle will require the whole application to start again, including doing any runtime compilation that ASP does. That sounds like a performance nightmare if you need to do this with any sort of frequency.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a session key then the way can be, for each User:

```
Session.Remove(Session.SessionID);
```

Also you can update the session value to null: (This is what I am doing)

```
Session.Add(sessionKey, null);
```

Comment: That's for current user or for all users?

Comment: Actually I make unique Id for each user, So I remove by this method. Please try Session.Clear().

Answer (score 0):

I have a set of code in VB.Net to get active sessions in the system, you can kill it using a loop.

```
'''' Getting All Session
            Dim obj As Object = GetType(HttpRuntime).GetProperty("CacheInternal", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.[Static]).GetValue(Nothing, Nothing)
            Dim obj2 As Object() = DirectCast(obj.[GetType]().GetField("_caches", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(obj), Object())
            For i As Integer = 0 To obj2.Length - 1
                Dim c2 As Hashtable = DirectCast(obj2(i).[GetType]().GetField("_entries", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(obj2(i)), Hashtable)
                For Each entry As DictionaryEntry In c2
                    Dim o1 As Object = entry.Value.[GetType]().GetProperty("Value", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(entry.Value, Nothing)
                    If o1.[GetType]().ToString() = "System.Web.SessionState.InProcSessionState" Then
                        Dim sess As SessionStateItemCollection = DirectCast(o1.[GetType]().GetField("_sessionItems", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(o1), SessionStateItemCollection)
                        If sess IsNot Nothing Then
                            If sess("EmpCode") IsNot Nothing Then
                                Dt.Rows.Add(sess("EmpCode").ToString.Trim)
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
```