# Delete only one variable from all session at once

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

Let's presume that I have a session variable like this:

```
Session["Variable"] = "Assigned";
```

I can remove this variable for one user like this

```
Session.Remove("Variable");
```

Can I delete just this variable from all users? If yes, how?

Comment: You can't clear all session (if you don't recycle the complete app pool).

Comment: Thank you! I already search the google for two hours already though. And I think you didn't get the problem here.

Comment: @MethodMan: i don't think that it's simple because it's not possible to remove a session variable **for all sessions**. But it was asked before anyway, f.e. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172268/how-to-destroy-all-sessions-at-one-time-in-asp-net) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703577/asp-net-how-to-delete-all-session-variables-from-all-users). Maybe with [ugly reflection approaches](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/reading-all-users-session) which might work with inproc-sessions.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, and the solution was recycle the app pool, but it deletes all the sessions. And those questions are at least 3 years old. I just hope that there may be solution for this since new .net version is up.

Comment: @MethodMan: OP just wants to remove one session variable not kill all. That would also be a temporary outage of the webserver.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I know that.. and that's done by just `Removing` or using the `RemoveAll`

Comment: @MethodMan: No, that just removes one variable from the current session(or all from the current). OP wants something completely different. He wants to remove a specific variable from all sessions.

Comment: I got cha.. this question is a bit confusing at first glance

Comment: @MethodMan: not really, he mentions "from all session" in the title and "from all users" in the question body. He now even added that he knows how to remove it from a given session.

Comment: doesn't matter either way not sure why the OP wants to do this outside of recycling the AppPool which would not be a feasible approach.. it would be nice to know / understand why the OP feels they need to do this..

Comment: @MethodMan: that's a good question ;)

Comment: @jackjop, can you expand for us why you feel the need to do this, so that we can gain a better understanding of your thought process in regards to wanting to clear 1 session variable for all users.. this actually makes no sense to me

Comment: @MethodMan: there could be some use cases like giving an admin the possibility to clear specific session variables for all users (f.e. clear `UserID` to force all to login again).

Comment: I would still like to understand why the OP wants to do this vs speculation I still think we need more clarification on what the OP is trying to accomplish  and a better explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to precursor my answer with you asked "Can I...". Just because you can, doesn't mean you should. Also, to reiterate the above comments, why do you want to do this? There may be a flaw in your design. We can't help with that unless you help us understand.

It is theoretically possible for InProc sessions. However, I don't recommend it because it will not work in farms or on session solutions. There are also some thread safety issues you need to be aware of which brings me back to "why?".

However, I can answer the "Can I..." and not the "Should I..." It almost makes me cringe giving the answer. However, use this at your own risk and this is not tested.

Also, if you are using a caching server or other session state server, this gets thrown out the window.
 In your Global.asax or IoC container you can have a collection similar to this:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application["allSessions"] = new List<HttpSessionState>();
}

protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var allSessions= (List<HttpSessionState>)Application["allSessions"];
    sessions.Add(this.Session);
}

protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sessions = (List<HttpSessionState>)Application["allSessions"];
    sessions.Remove(this.Session);
}
```

Then you can pull the session variable of allSessions, which is hacky IMHO and iterate over them.

Again, please read the recommendations above from other comments. Remember there is more than one way to skin a cat.