# How to access IIS through C# Console Application

Tags: c#, iis

I am trying to access my server's IIS pool in order to recycle it through C# code.

This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        string sMachine = "MyHostName";
        string sAppPool = "MyAppPoolName";

        string sPath = "IIS://" + sMachine + "/W3SVC/AppPools/" + sAppPool;
        Console.WriteLine(sPath);

        DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry(sPath, "MyUserName", "MyPassword");
        w3svc.Invoke("Recycle", null);

        Console.WriteLine("Application pool recycled");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I changed the sMachine / sAppPool / UserName, Password, but in my code I send them with the real data.

When I run it on my VM I get a message

```
Error: Unknown Exception
```

I think it occurs because the permission so I run it with the administrator of the VM and run as administrator the exe file, but still I get the same error.

How could I access the IIS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically recycle a .net web app's own apppool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470132/how-can-i-programmatically-recycle-a-net-web-apps-own-apppool)