# Kill current worker process in c# without HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable error

Tags: c#

I am trying to kill current worker process and i am successful in that but when i hit the site again it throws HTTP Error 503 the service is unavailable error and to fix this i have to run iisreset command. But when i kill the w3wp using taskmanager End task command a and hit the site again it works perfect.

What wrong i am doing in below code.

```
    Protected void BtnKill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var CurrentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        if (CurrentProcess != null)
        {
            CurrentProcess.Kill();
            CurrentProcess.WaitForExit();
            CurrentProcess.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have questions...so many questions, but mainly... why?

Comment: Are you trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470132/how-can-i-programmatically-recycle-a-net-web-apps-own-apppool)?

Comment: Let me check if the code works

Comment: You should look for error solution like why Service unavailable 503 error comes at first place.

Comment: @john the link you given didn't solved my problem

Comment: @Manish But is that what you're trying to do - to force the application to be recycled?

Comment: i tried your code but thats not killing old process id and generating new process id, which happens when you kill w3wp using taskmanager end task click

Comment: I'll rephrase: What is your goal? What are you doing this for? Why do you want a new process id?

Comment: One of my site is running on shared hosting and i have created a taskmanager.aspx page which is displaying all running worker process and i want a button when click will kill my worker process and create a new worker process when site is hit again

Comment: Or simply if you open your task manager and kill w3wp using end task command you will notice that a new worker process will get created when you hit the site again, i want same functionality using c#